# Why does changing the order of constructor function calls cause it to malfunction?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The function below creates a calculator which at first supports only addition and subtraction of two numbers, but can be extended with the "this.addMethod" to accommodate other operators, like "/", "*", and "**".

However, when I add a new calculator via the constructor ("new") and add new operations to it, the power operation("**") works properly only if it is called first.

The full code below:

```js
function Calculator() {
  this.supportedOperators = ['+', '-'];

  this.supportedMethods = [
    (a, b) => a + b,
    (a, b) => a - b
  ];

  this.calculate = (str) => {
    for (operator of this.supportedOperators) {
      if (str.includes(operator)) {
        let delimiter = operator.length; // for '**' operator
        let firstOperand = str.slice(0, str.indexOf(operator));
        let secondOperand = str.slice(str.indexOf(operator) + delimiter);

        return this.supportedMethods[this.supportedOperators.findIndex(item => item === operator)]
          (+firstOperand, +secondOperand);
        /* check the supported operators, then use it on operands
                           
                            A mess here, but i tried my best to make it more readable and understandable */

      } else console.log('Unsupported operation');
    }
  };

  this.addMethod = (operator, method) => {
    this.supportedOperators.push(operator);
    this.supportedMethods.push(method);
  }

}

let powerCalc = new Calculator;

powerCalc.addMethod("**", (a, b) => a ** b); // works fine
powerCalc.addMethod("*", (a, b) => a * b);
powerCalc.addMethod("/", (a, b) => a / b);


let result = powerCalc.calculate("4 ** 3"); // 64, as should be(other values also supported)
console.log(result);
```

However, if I change the order in the last sequence of code, so that the addition of "**" operation is no longer the first, like this:

```js
function Calculator() {
  this.supportedOperators = ['+', '-'];

  this.supportedMethods = [
    (a, b) => a + b,
    (a, b) => a - b
  ];

  this.calculate = (str) => {
    for (operator of this.supportedOperators) {
      if (str.includes(operator)) {
        let delimiter = operator.length; // for '**' operator
        let firstOperand = str.slice(0, str.indexOf(operator));
        let secondOperand = str.slice(str.indexOf(operator) + delimiter);

        return this.supportedMethods[this.supportedOperators.findIndex(item => item === operator)]
          (+firstOperand, +secondOperand);
        /* check the supported operators, then use it on operands
                           
                            A mess here, but i tried my best to make it more readable and understandable */

      } else console.log('Unsupported operation');
    }
  };

  this.addMethod = (operator, method) => {
    this.supportedOperators.push(operator);
    this.supportedMethods.push(method);
  }

}

let powerCalc = new Calculator;

powerCalc.addMethod("*", (a, b) => a * b); // 
powerCalc.addMethod("/", (a, b) => a / b); // those two work fine regardless of order
powerCalc.addMethod("**", (a, b) => a ** b); // changed the order, no works fine

let result = powerCalc.calculate("4 ** 3"); // throws NaN with any value
console.log(result);
```

The power operation now returns NaN.

I am at a loss trying to figure it out. Please help.

Comment: The expression string involving `"**"` includes the string `"*"`.

Comment: `if (str.includes(operator)) {` will already run with `operator` being `*`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with constructor functions. The construction function `Calculator` is called at the same point in both examples.

Comment: You should probably _sort_ by descending operator length to avoid such issues. (That you are keeping operators and methods in two separate arrays, makes that a bit harder of course - you will have to sort the methods in the same order, that sorting of the operators resulted in. Or find a more appropriate data structure to begin with - one that keeps operator and method inside of one single “item”, so that you can sort the whole list of such items by operator length in one go.)

Comment: if is making a condition true when loop is checking the string first with `*` as the input `4 ** 3` contains the `*` in it

Comment: You should prefer the descending order, operator with maximum length should check first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments put it above, the problem was that the `**` and `*` operators both contain the "*" symbol. One of the proposed solutions was to implement `sort()` so that the operators with longest length would come first.

The other was to use a different data structure, and i decided to went with it. The code is given below:

```
function Calculator() {

  this.methods = {
    "-": (a, b) => a - b,
    "+": (a, b) => a + b
  };

  this.calculate = function(str) {

    let split = str.split(' '), 
      a = +split[0],
      operator = split[1],
      b = +split[2] // split the input string into an array of two operands converted to numbers and an operator

    if (!this.methods[operator] || isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
      return NaN;
    }

    return this.methods[operator](a, b);
  }

  this.addMethod = function(name, func) {
    this.methods[name] = func;
  };
}

let powerCalc = new Calculator;

powerCalc.addMethod("*", (a, b) => a * b);
powerCalc.addMethod("/", (a, b) => a / b);
powerCalc.addMethod("**", (a, b) => a ** b); // the order doesn't matter anymore

let result = powerCalc.calculate("4 ** 3"); 
alert( result ); // 64, as it should be
```

Thanks everyone for the input!

Also one of the comments pointed out that the question name was not relevant to the actual problem i encountered. I will edit it shortly, when i come up with a better idea. Sorry for the confusion, i'm just starting to learn JS.
If you have an idea on how to better name the question, please post it in the comments.